# Incorrect Validation Rule Result

Tags: validation-rule

I've got this odd situation with a validation rule. The intent is to display an error when a picklist field does not have a specific value and a lookup field is blank. What actually happens is that it ignores the picklist values entirely.

Here's the validation rule:

```
ISBLANK( integration_partner__c )
&& NOT(ISPICKVAL(Data_Capture_Method__c, "Manual Agent"))
&& NOT(ISPICKVAL(Channel__c, "Agent"))
```

In the above Integration_Partner__c is a lookup, while the other 2 are pick-list fields.

As you can see in the screen capture below, the rule is still evaluating to true even though it's clear that Data_Capture_Method__c method is "Manual Agent". If I evaluate that logic manually it should be interpreted as True && NOT(True) && NOT(False), which should evaluate to False.

[image: screen_capture]

Is there something else I'm missing on this?

Comment: Did you try just using TEXT instead like TEXT(Data_Capture_Method__c) <> 'Manual Agent'

Comment: Yes, but I get the same result. Really strange.

Comment: Sure there is not an extra space in there, or there is a duplicate validation rule, or duplicate field? The validation rule looks ok to me.

Comment: Ugh! The value "Manual Agent" looked good in the list of Picklist values, but when it was created (not by me though), it was in there with 2 spaces ("Manual  Agent"). Oddly, if you copy that value from the list of picklist values or even see it in the picklist (i.e., the screen capture), Salesforce does not show the 2 spaces.  It's working now!

Comment: even worse is when the copy-paste is from a web page and the space is a nbsp or, in the situation of dashes, an `em` instead of a hyphen. Glad you found it